# making dropdown with optgroup using php nested array list

Tags: php, arrays, optgroup

I have this nested array and i want to convert it into dropdown ,but at output it is just showing me combo-box with options as (array ,array,array)

```
 <select name="pcity" id="pcity" multiple="multiple">

<?php
$pcitylist = array('Andaman and Nicobar' => array('North and Middle Andaman',
    'South Andaman', 'Nicobar'), 'Andhra Pradesh' => array('Adilabad', 'Anantapur',
    'Chittoor', 'East Godavari', 'Guntur', 'Hyderabad', 'Kadapa', 'Karimnagar',
    'Khammam', 'Krishna', 'Kurnool', 'Mahbubnagar', 'Medak', 'Nalgonda', 'Nellore',
    'Nizamabad', 'Prakasam', 'Rangareddi', 'Srikakulam', 'Vishakhapatnam',
    'Vizianagaram', 'Warangal', 'West Godavari'), 'Arunachal Pradesh' => array('Anjaw',
    'Changlang', 'East Kameng', 'Lohit', 'Lower Subansiri', 'Papum Pare', 'Tirap',
    'Dibang Valley', 'Upper Subansiri', 'West Kameng'));
foreach ($pcitylist as $pcitylist1) {
    echo '<option value="' . $pcitylist1 . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && $_POST['pcity'] ==
        $pcitylist1 ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $pcitylist1 . '</option>';
}              

 ?>         
 </select>
```

i want it to display like this

```
<select>
<optgroup>Andaman and Nicobar</optgroup>
<option>North and Middle Andaman</option>
<option>South Andaman</option>.....
</select>
```

and so on...

Comment: `<select>
<optgroup>Andaman and Nicobar</optgroup>
<option>Adilabad</option>
<option>Anantapur</option>
</select>` Syntax is not correct.

Comment: @PankitKapadia you should show him the correct syntax.

Comment: The correct syntax would be: `<select><optgroup label="Andaman And Nicobar"><option>Adilabad</option><option>Anantapur</option><option></option></optgroup></select>`

Comment: @beerwin - thanks showing him on behalf of me..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($pcitylist as $key => $pcitylist1)
{
      echo '<optgroup label="'.$key.'">';
      foreach ($pcitylist1 as $finalCity) {
          echo '<option value="' . $finalCity . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && $_POST['pcity'] == $finalCity ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $finalCity . '</option>';
      }   
      echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

The `$key` holds the optgroup label. This will work with your array.

Comment: Thanks a lot it gave me proper output

Answer (score 1):

It is an multidimensional array... use one more for loop inside ur for loop and u will get the ouput..

Try the following..

```
foreach ($pcitylist as $key => $pcitylist1)
{ 
      foreach ($pcitylist1 as $finalCity) {
          echo '<option value="' . $finalCity . '"' . (isset($_POST['pcity']) && $_POST['pcity'] == $finalCity ? ' selected' : '') . '>'.$key . $finalCity . '</option>';
      }    
}
```

Comment: Thnks for your responce ,with your code I am getting List options only ,i want list options with their group name ,as we get it using <optgroup> tag .Means i want option Group name also to come in that list

Comment: use this variable inside forloop to access group name.. $pcitylist1

Comment: since i am new to php can u write how to use this $pcitylist1  in for loop ,so i can get result

Comment: it was showing $key with all option ,which i wanted ones ,well thanks i got it solved .