# PHP Recursive Function to output select

Tags: php, arrays, select, recursive-datastructures

I must have blocked out something, I know the answer is simple but for the life of my I cant get any clear answers from Google. 
I have this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Paint
        [parent_id] => 0
        [sub] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [name] => Dulux
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [sub] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 6
                                        [name] => Roof Cover
                                        [parent_id] => 4
                                        [sub] => Array
                                            (
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 5
                        [name] => Plascon
                        [parent_id] => 1
                        [sub] => Array
                            (
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [name] => Electrical
        [parent_id] => 0
        [sub] => Array
            (
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => Plumbing
        [parent_id] => 0
        [sub] => Array
            (
            )
    )
)
```

and want to output a select, with option groups. I know this is a 101 PHP thing but been working on this for to long now to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this out, similar issue, may guide you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874186/making-dropdown-with-optgroup-using-php-nested-array-list

Comment: _"but been working on this for to long now"_ - Show us what you've come up with and we can help you from there.

Comment: It'd be very helpful if you could post the expected html you want from this recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirt simple recursive function:

```
function output_option($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if ($item['sub']) {
            echo '<optgroup label="', $item['name'], '">';
            output_option($arr['sub']);
            echo '</optgroup>';
        } else {
            echo '<option id="', $arr['name'], '">', $arr['name'], '</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to modify/change it for your needs, but it should be fairly self explanatory.

Comment: you could use array.strlen()== 0 for first exit condition and replace the foreach, sending to the recursion the $arr[index + 1] ?